# React native function is not working the way it supposed to be

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here is my function:

```
setActive = (item) => {
    this.setState({ active: !item.active });
    item.active = !item.active;
    console.log("Before update: ", !item.active);
  };
```

here is how I use it:

```
     import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

import { styles } from "./styles";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createStructuredSelector } from "reselect";
import { getAccounts } from "../../redux/user/selectors";

const UserMenuAccount = ({ active, account, balance }) => (
  <View style={styles.accountContainer}>
    <Image
      source={require("../../../assets/Usermenu/check.png")}
      style={[styles.icon, { opacity: active ? 1 : 0 }]}
    />
    <Text style={styles.text}>{account}</Text>
    <Text style={[styles.text, { opacity: 0.5 }]}>{balance} ETH</Text>
  </View>
);

class UserMenuAccounts extends Component {
  state = {
    active: false,
    usersList:[]
  };

  setActive = (item) => {
    this.setState({ active: !item.active });
    item.active = !item.active;
    console.log("Before update: ", !item.active);
  };

  render() {
    const { GetAccounts } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={{ opacity: 0.5, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
          Click to switch
        </Text>
        <View>
          {GetAccounts.map((users, index, active) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setActive(index, users, active);
                  this.disableActive(users);
                }}
                key={index}
              >
                <UserMenuAccount
                  account={`${users.username}`}
                  balance={0}
                  active={users.active}
                  key={index}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          })}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  GetAccounts: getAccounts,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(UserMenuAccounts);
```

**GetAccounts** is a selector from redux store.

It contains this Array of objects:

```
    ---- Array [
  Object {
    "active": false,
    "username": "Nikolozi",
  },
  Object {
    "active": false,
    "username": "ghg",
  },
]
```

All I'm trying to do is,When button is clicked **active** property of object is changing to **true** BUT the problem is **when i press on second button and It turns into true,the active value of first item is not changing to false** any suggestions please on how to achieve this??

Comment: but why the first item should change to false after you tap the second one? your code doesn't do it

Comment: Its what i m trying to achieve and I thought the way I wrote it it would work

Comment: @no_fate could you help me please?

Comment: I mean in your code you didn't add any line to change the first item

Comment: but how can i target it ? by filtering selector to find the one with active:true?

Comment: setActive function changes the only item that you tapped

Comment: that means i shall add another function which targets the items which has active:true?

Comment: if you use redux than you need to dispatch actions to change your store, but you change local state

Comment: could you share the code of your whole component?

Comment: @no_fate yes i will update the question

Comment: @no_fate updated

Comment: Your component is already connected with the global store, all you need is to change data properly. For that, you need to change the store data, after they update your page will be rerendered. To change the store you need to dispatch an action. After that, you need to change your store in a reducer function, and in the reducer, you can manipulate all data that you want to change

Comment: so you don't need your local component state at all

Comment: I think I got what you wanted to do. Just try to save in local state an index of item that you want to display as active, and in render with map function of GetAccounts add a check that the index of account is the same as you saved, and display it as active if yes